# Роль сервлетов в Model-View-Controller (mvc)

Tags: mvc

Если задача шаблона Model-View-Controller `mvc` дать возможность независимо модифицировать модель в смысле бизнес-логики,  вид в смысле `jsp` или чего-то что будет выводить данные для пользователя, и контроллера в смысле `Servlet`(поправьте пожалуйста если я тут ошибаюсь).

То я правильно понимаю что:

Сервлеты не должны иметь никакой бизнес логики, а только использовать интерфейс модуля который за эту логику отвечает, и не должны вносить изменений в структуру `jsp`/`html`, а только передавать параметры между моделью и видом?

Comment: Сервлет не имеет никакого отношения к MVC. Сервлет обеспечивает работу приложения в модели запрос-ответ.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/332857/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-mvc?rq=1